# Msbuild with bitbucket pipeline

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, bitbucket

We have multiple .NET projects (.NETFramework 4.7.1) in our own bitbucket repository. We like to implement continous integration so that every check in the the repository should run automatic unit testing and create build and upload the build to an AWS S3 bucket. I could not find any useful information for this.

We are not using .NET Core. And we need to use MSBuild.

Answer (score 4):

I'm facing the same issue. 
MSBuild is currently not supported, but there is an open 'proposal' for this feature [here](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/13452/support-for-native-windows-net-builds-on).

It seems they are working on it with Microsoft, and the estimate is to have a product by mid-2019:

> (...) it is unlikely that we'll have anything production ready for Bitbucket users until mid-2019, always subject to change based on the progress on the blocking issues.

Meanwhile we can vote for the proposal in a way to show our interest.

Comment: Good gracious, hard to believe BB does not support this yet!

Comment: Any update on this? is BB support MSbuild now ?

Comment: It seems they have added support for self hosted only https://bitbucket.org/blog/windows-runners